# capistrano 3 cannot access git repository deploying on vps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, ssh, capistrano

please help! have no idea where to start

deploy.rb
    lock '3.1.0'
    set :application, 'baza'
    set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/baza'
    set :repo_url,  "deploy@100.100.100.100:/home/deploy/git/baza.git"

```
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle    public/system}

namespace :deploy do

 desc 'Restart application'
task :restart do
on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
  execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
end
end

after :publishing, 'deploy:restart'
after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'
end
```

and get the error

```
←[0;34;49mINFO←[0m[←[0;32;49md08a4f3a←[0m] Running ←[0;33;49m/usr/bin/env mkdir-p /tmp/baza/←[0m on ←[0;34;49m107.170.154.188←[0m
←[0;30;49mDEBUG←[0m[←[0;32;49md08a4f3a←[0m] Command: ←[0;34;49m/usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/baza/←[0m
←[0;34;49mINFO←[0m[←[0;32;49md08a4f3a←[0m] Finished in 5.022 seconds with exit status 0 (←[0;32;49msuccessful←[0m).
←[0;30;49mDEBUG←[0mUploading /tmp/baza/git-ssh.sh 0.0%
←[0;34;49mINFO←[0mUploading /tmp/baza/git-ssh.sh 100.0%
[0;34;49mINFO←[0m[←[0;32;49me25bbb96←[0m] Running ←[0;33;49m/usr/bin/env chmod+x /tmp/baza/git-ssh.sh←[0m on ←[0;34;49m107.170.154.188←[0m
←[0;30;49mDEBUG←[0m[←[0;32;49me25bbb96←[0m] Command: ←[0;34;49m/usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/baza/git-ssh.sh←[0m
←[0;34;49mINFO←[0m[←[0;32;49me25bbb96←[0m] Finished in 0.774 seconds with exit status 0 (←[0;32;49msuccessful←[0m).
[0;30;49mDEBUG←[0m[←[0;32;49m2a0546ea←[0m] Running ←[0;33;49m/usr/bin/env git ls-remote deploy@100.100.100.100:/home/deploy/git/baza.git←[0m on             ←[0;34;49m107.170.154.188←[0m
←[0;30;49mDEBUG←[0m[←[0;32;49m2a0546ea←[0m] Command: ←[0;34;49m( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/baza/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote deploy@100.100.100.100:/home/deploy/git/baza.git )←[0m
←[0;30;49mDEBUG←[0m[←[0;32;49m2a0546ea←[0m] ←[0;31;49m  Error reading response length from authentication socket.
←[0m←[0;30;49mDEBUG←[0m[←[0;32;49m2a0546ea←[0m] ←[0;31;49m      Permission denied (publickey,password).
←[0m←[0;30;49mDEBUG←[0m[←[0;32;49m2a0546ea←[0m] ←[0;31;49m      fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
←[0m←[0;30;49mDEBUG←[0m[←[0;32;49m2a0546ea←[0m] ←[0;31;49m
←[0m←[0;30;49mDEBUG←[0m[←[0;32;49m2a0546ea←[0m] ←[0;31;49m      Please make sure you have the correct access rights
←[0m←[0;30;49mDEBUG←[0m[←[0;32;49m2a0546ea←[0m] ←[0;31;49m      and the repository exists.
←[0m←[0;30;49mDEBUG←[0m[←[0;32;49m2a0546ea←[0m] Finished in 1.238 seconds with exit     status 128 (←[0;31;49mfailed←[0m). cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host 100.100.100.100:
```

please give me a clue where to start!

Answer (score 0):

please check

```
:repo_url, "deploy@100.100.100.100:/home/deploy/git/baza.git"
```

Are you sure your git user is "deploy"?

Comment: that's what i get by git remote -v

Comment: check
> ssh deploy@100.100.100.100

Comment: simply type in console: ssh deploy@100.100.100.100

Answer (score 0):

we live the same problem our solution was add to **deploy.rb**:

```
set :ssh_options, {
  keys: %w(/home/usuario/.ssh/id_rsa),
  forward_agent: false,
  auth_methods: %w(publickey)
}
```

and works great!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to your `VPS` via `SSH`

and run

```
deploy@baza:~$ ssh -T git@github.com
deploy@baza:~$ ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
deploy@baza:~$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
deploy@baza:~$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC+... deploy@baza
```

2. Add generated public key `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` for example as `Baza deploy@100.100.100.100` to your GitHub / BitBucket `Baza` repository `SSH Keys` settings section.
3. Re-upload project.